# php global variables with variable names

Tags: php

I am trying to have a function that among other things declares global variables based on a variable that i give it.
the part that fails is making the variables global

```
function setGlobalVariable($name) {

    global $name, $arrayname_{$name};
}
```

any idea? 
thanks :)

Comment: why would you want to pollute the global namespace with variables?

Comment: poor developer, who will support the code you've written.

Comment: Only one: Avoid global variables. Usually they are a powerful source of troubles (and you don't need them).

Comment: I agree with you all about the poor use of Global variables. What i am trying to do is write a function that does MSQL query and returns all the variables needed. Not only the array of the query but also mysql_query() & mysql_num_rows() for other uses such as a do loop to display the results. I would love to have a better way to do this but I am not an expert. Any suggestions?

Comment: Then create dependent functions that have arguments for passing results to and from other functions, instead of using the global namespace as a temporary holding area - the latter is like throwing your garbage on the street expecting that someone will pick it up later

Comment: Perhaps this is not the ideal place for this but I am curious about the difference between having $a = 123; declared outside a function and having $a declared as global from inside a function. I was under the impression that it is the same. I guess there lies my first mistake no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Really, stop messing with global variables that way.

Anywaym here's your solution if you really want to do that:

```
function setGlobalVariable($name) {
    $GLOBALS['arrayname_' . $name] = 'yourvalue';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not do that. Global variables are in general a sign of poor design. What is it that you are trying to achieve? I am sure that there is a better solution. Besides that, `global` does not work like that. `global` makes other variables outside your function locally available. Use `$_GLOBAL` to create globals.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Registry Pattern (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html).

> A well-known object that other objects
>   can use to find common objects and
>   services.

There are various PHP implementations, for example Zend_Registry: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.html

Answer (score 0):

You're almost right, but not quite; a variable variable takes the form of `${"name"}`, so what you're looking for is something like `global ${"arrayname_$name"};`.

http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/dst56/today_i_learned_about_php_variable_variables/c12np38 is fascinating reading on the topic, if you feel so inclined.

It's likely a terrible idea, though, and if you're resorting to that sort of thing, it's a good indication that your code may be poorly designed. Consider refactoring it (for example, to keep a single known array that your other arrays are kept in, and may be referenced by key.)